# How to handle simultaneous read-write operations in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, concurrency, locking

I'm struggling with concurrency access to a document of a mongoDB.
I would clarify some concepts.
I'm using mongoose

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp');
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
name:String,
numAvailableProduct:3,
customer:[{name:String}]
})
const ProductModel = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema );
ProductModel.findOneAndUpdate({name:"table",numAvailableProduct:{$gt:0}} , {$inc:{numAvailableProduct:-1}})
```

I'm simulating a purchase of a product.
With the method `findOneAndUpdate` I'm reading if there is availability for the table product (`numAvailableProduct>0`) and if it is the case I decrease by 1 the `numAvailableProduct`

`findOneAndUpdate` on the same document is **atomic** namely either it exec both the instructions or they fail.
In MongoDb there is `maxPoolSize` that it sets the number of sockets that can make requests at the same time so even if the operation is atomic someone could read the value of `numAvailableProduct` before the write happens and could find `3` instead than `2` (In this way rather than a double decrement eventually I get a single decrement). I should lock my document or my collection or my database when I exec `findOneAndUpdate` to avoid this problem.
Is it right this? And how could I get a lock in mongoDB with mongoose?

Comment: If all updates are done using similar `findOneAndUpdate`, you won't run into concurrency issues. Even if there are multiple concurrent requests, those will run one after the other on a single document. If you have a read-then-update situation, then you need to use transactions to prevent concurrency issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. So MongoDb automatically take a lock of the document either in read mode and in write mode? Thereby I have ony to assure atomicity of my operations. Can you confirm? And what if I have `findOneAndUpdate` on more fields (more updates) of the same document? (It should be still an atomic operation)

Comment: A single `findOneAndUpdate` operation, no matter how many fields it updates, is atomic. All concurrent update operations on that same document will be serialized. The document will be locked throughout the operation, i.e. no other operation can take place between the read and update.

Comment: yes, I watched the documentation. It's like that with an exception, when in the options of `findOneAndUpdate` I use `{upsert: true}` to update the document when a document isn't found

Comment: In the case of upsert, the insertion would be atomic. With many concurrent requests, the first one processed would create the document, and the filters for the remaining calls would be evaluated after that.